# Use of "the" in the middle of a sentence

Tags: grammar, articles

I have the following sentences:

1. We show that in the presence of X, in conjunction with Y, Z is obtained due to the interference between **the** A and B channels, oscillating at the frequency W.
2. Now, A involves a sum over all such paths involving different excitations, with the coefficients of **the** A and B terms being similar to the components of the C.

I have highlighted the "the"s which are confusing me. Is it grammatically correct to have them? In both cases, the objects denoted by A and B have been introduced in earlier sentences.

Comment: Yes, if you have already introduced the terms/channels, it is certainly correct.

Comment: Personally I would keep the highlighted article in the first example, but REMOVE the superfluous articles before ***interference*** AND ***frequency***. The second example I would leave as is. As a side issue, I think initial ***Now*** in the second example is a "chatty, informal" usage more suited to children''s stories than formal technical texts.

Answer (score -1):

If A and B are specific and not generic, then "the" should be used.

Comment: Article choice is a very complex topic. Can you go into a lot more detail on what you mean? Does this apply to all situations in English, or just this context? If this context, why does it apply? Does the fact the A and B were already mentioned earlier in the context have no bearing?